# Load balancer does not balance load properly

Tags: java, load, ejb, wildfly, load-balancing

We have an EJB application deployed in two Wildfly servers. The two servers are load balanced. The external application which is calling our application cals the load ba;ancer URL, which then distributes the request to the two servers in round robin fashion.
The issue is the load is not properly balanced. This is because The external application makes RMI calls to the load balancer which is over TCP. I heard that for TCP connection, the external application opens a socket to the load balancer which in turn opens another socket to application on one of our servers and thus connection is established between the calling application and one of the servers. This connection does not end until the connection is broken and thus the load always goes to one server even though it is load balanced.

Can anyone suggest a solution for properly distributing the load between two servers?

Comment: What version of wildfly are you using? What are your client -> server connections? web requests, remote ejb?

Comment: What load balancer are you using?

Comment: We are using wildfly 8, and remote ejb calls.

Comment: So you are connecting over websocket. Things changed quite a bit with three move to the websocket. In the past there was code in the ejb client to discover the other servers in your ha cluster, so no need for http load balancer, you just used the ha profile on server

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EJB+Services

Comment: Looks like despite the move to websockets, it might still support client's discovering other nodes in the cluster (or the doc is out of date)